# Check if user exists in table through SQL

Tags: sql, asp.net, .net, validation

I'm trying to make a function on my "create user" form in ASP.NET.

I have tried to figure out how I get an if statement on a SQL validation function from my class file, to see if the username and email has been used.

This is what I tried to do.

---

Class file:

```
public DataTable ValidateUSER(string Username)
{
    string SQL = "SELECT fldUsername FROM tblBruger WHERE fldUsername LIKE 
    @username";

    SqlCommand CMD = new SqlCommand(SQL);

    CMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", Username);

    return DA.GetData(CMD);
}
```

My codebehind:

```
LoginClass objLogin = new LoginClass();

 protected void ButtonCheck_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string txtUser = txtUsername.Text;


    if (obj.ValidateUSER(txtUser) == txtUser)
    {
        litResult.Text = "Username already taken";
    }
```

Comment: You are never executing the SQL Command, see this page of the docs: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fksx3b4f.aspx

Comment: have you thought of using the default boilerplate created by Asp.NET when a new application is created? Simply create a new app with individual user accounts and all of this is done for you, no need to reinvent the wheel on this one

Comment: Never heard og boilerplate? This is a school assignment, so we have to work with, what they teach us.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what `DA` is but I'm guessing it is some sort of data access framework that will execute the supplied command and return a data table.  If this is the case, you just need to make a small modification.

```
public string ValidateUser(string userName)
{
    string sql = "SELECT fldUsername FROM tblBruger WHERE fldUsername LIKE @username";
    SqlCommand cmd= new SqlCommand(sql);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", userName);
    DataTable table = DA.GetData(cmd);
    if (table.Rows.Count != 0) 
    {
        return table.Rows[0].Item[0] as string;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Also a tweak here.  Note I made the check case-insensitive, which seems sensible for a user name:

```
var s = obj.ValidateUser(txtUserName.Text);
if (s != null && s.ToLower() == txtUserName.Text.ToLower())
{
    litResult.Text = "Username already taken";
}
```

Note also I changed the capitalization of some of your identifiers so that they are consistent with the [C# coding conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff926074.aspx) published by Microsoft.

Comment: I fixed it, thanks! Your code didn't work. I kept the SQL the same just changed

if (s != null)
{
    litResult.Text = "Username already taken";
}

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [SqlDataReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
string SQL = "SELECT fldUsername FROM tblBruger WHERE fldUsername LIKE 
    @username";

SqlCommand CMD = new SqlCommand(SQL); 

SqlDataReader rdr = CMD.ExecuteReader();

while (rdr.Read())
{
//do something with result set
}
```